# Find highest bill (note) from array

Tags: php, math, logic

I need to find the highest note from an array of notes I have. I already have the code to find the highest, but I need to take that array and find the highest from those. I've been stumped trying to figure this out.

```
$famount = $number;
$denom = array(1000, 2000, 5000, 10000, 20000, 50000);

function coin_change ($amount, $bills)
{
  $change = array();
  rsort($bills);
  for($i=0; $i<count($bills); $i++) {
    $change[$bills[$i]] = floor($amount/$bills[$i]);
    $amount = $amount % $bills[$i];
    echo $bills[$i] . " " .$change[$bills[$i]] ."<br>";
  }
    return $change;
} 

$money = coin_change($famount, $denom);
```

With the above code, I pass in a variable I type in and it finds the highest bills as you can see in the array. How is it possible to take those bills and then find the highest of those?

Expected example result from above function:

50000: 1

20000: 0

10000: 1

5000: 1

2000:  1

1000: 1

Desired result based on above result:

50000: 0

20000: 2

10000: 1

5000: 2

1000: 3

Thank you.

Comment: Try to use max($array)

Comment: can you explain further - with example data and expected results perhaps?

Comment: Sorry, with the above code I receive the maximum bills for the value entered, that's works great. Let's say I type in 16k, so it shows 1 10k note, 1 5k note, and 1 1k note. I need to then take those notes and break them down to their highest amounts. This is really difficult for me to work, I apologize.

Comment: Can you please provide us your expected result? That would help us to give you the solution.

Comment: Added above to question.

Comment: Unclear question. Your example does not match up. In the first example the sum is 68000 and in the output you want 63000.

Answer (score 0):

If you only add notes that is not zero you can just echo the first key in the return array.

```
$denom = array(1000, 2000, 5000, 10000, 20000, 50000);

function coin_change ($amount, $bills)
{
   $change = array();
   rsort($bills);
   for($i=0; $i<count($bills); $i++) {
       If($bills[$i] <= $amount){ // only add notes that is more than one
           $change[$bills[$i]] = floor($amount/$bills[$i]);
           $amount = $amount % $bills[$i];
           echo $bills[$i] . " " .$change[$bills[$i]] ."<br>\n";
       }
    }
    return $change;
} 

$money = coin_change(15000, $denom);
//$money = [10000, 5000];

// Echo only the first note (largest)
Foreach($money as $key => $m){
    Echo $key; // 10000
    Break;
}
```

https://3v4l.org/Ko5SV

Comment: Sorry, with the above code I receive the maximum bills for the value entered, that's works great. Let's say I type in 16k, so it shows 1 10k note, 1 5k note, and 1 1k note. I need to then take those notes and break them down to their highest amounts. This is really difficult for me to work, I apologize